# Case statement for null Records

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my scenario

I have a table with columns Country and State. I have only one row with values USA and NY.

Now if the user chooses NY then I have to display 'New York' and if other than NY then display 'No Records'.

I tried the below Oracle sql and it is failing for me. When I enter other state like MA, I am expecting 'No Records', but I get null value.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN STATE='NY' THEN 'New York'
            when state  <> 'NY' THEN 'No Records' end
from 
  abc
where 
  state in ('&state')
```

Please advise.

Comment: try : SELECT STATE CASE 'NY' THEN 'New York' ELSE 'No Records' end from abc where state in ('&state')

Comment: You are probably not getting a row because there is no `MA` state in `abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ELSE` instead.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN STATE='NY' THEN 'New York'
            ELSE 'No Records' end
from 
  abc
where 
  state in ('&state')
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. But ELSE also do not Work. I still get the NULL Value

Comment: @Pratap [Check this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6dea5/6) where its working properly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that you get at one row, use aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN max(STATE) = 'NY' THEN 'New York'
             ELSE 'No Records'
        END)
from abc
where state in ('&state');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why to reinvent the wheel? The `CASE WHEN THEN...ELSE...` is equivalent to `DECODE` :

`SELECT  DECODE(STATE, 'NY', 'New York', 'No Records') FROM TABLE`

The above decode means, when the state has value = 'NY', then display as 'New York', for anything else, display default value as 'No Records'.

**NOTE :** It is just that in case of multiple conditions checking, `CASE` is simpler to write when compared to `DECODE`. Also Decode can not be used in PL/SQL code where as CASE is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a waste to query the table if you don't plan on giving results when the user doesn't pick NY. Might as well wrap it in an IF/ELSE.

```
IF ('&state' = 'NY') BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM ABC
WHERE state in ('&state')
END

ELSE BEGIN
SELECT "No Records"
END
```

p.s. I have no experience with Oracle, you may need to change the syntax.

Comment: You can't mix procedural code with SQL statements in Oracle. Your statement will not work